# How do I build a hybrid chatbot using Watson Conversation?

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson

I would like to integrate 'live chat' interface with Watson Conversation, so that, when the user's question falls under off_topic then that question is sent to the live chat agent and he/she can take up the chat from there. In short, Watson giving a hand-off to the live agent at the other end when it doesn't have a proper response.

How can I achieve this task? I understand that when the confidence level goes below certain limit let's say <0.7 score then we can take that as a trigger for the watson to send it to the agent. But, I am more interested in learning how do I accomplish this task at "code level".

"NEED SOME HELP WITH THE CODE" - You may choose to use the "Full Car Dashboard' sample code and give me the solution as an example.

Help in this regard, would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I have details on how to handle answers in relation to confidence [here](https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/05/handling-low-confidence-answers-in-conversation/). The link contains a sample workspace demonstrating it.

For answer purposes you would in your condition node first check that an intent has been found. For example:

```
intents.size() > 0
```

After that you can check the confidence like so.

```
intents[0].confidence < 0.7
```

Once you have that, then it is just a simple matter of either passing back a keyword or a context variable to your application layer. Your application layer can then take over and hand over the conversation.

Comment: Hi @Simon O'Doherty, thank you for your response. I got the confidence score part. Can you tell me how do I accomplish this part of the what you have explained "Once you have that, then it is just a simple matter of either passing back a keyword or a context variable to your application layer. Your application layer can then take over and hand over the conversation." Need help with the coding part, please!

Comment: That's not really what stackoverflow is intended for. You could try on developerworks.

Answer (score 0):

as Simon stated you can pass tack to your application layer a signal to then perform additional tasks. One method is to include additional elements into the output component of the JSON packet returned by WCS. i.e.

```
{
   "output": {
        "text": "its nice to meet you @names, how can I help?",
        "flag": "Pass_to_real_person"
   },
   "context": {
        "name": "@names"
   }
}
```

Your application at the service layer will note the "flag" element within the output JSON packet and then perform the required task.
 
There are may example applications that can demonstrate how to parse a JSON file / payload to access the elements.

Comment: Can anyone please highlight or show an example where the call can be executed to a human agent, when Watson's reply confidence level goes down? A working example or an example code, please!